# How to get InputStream back from String

Tags: java, android, inputstream, raw-data, httpentity

Have a scenario where the httpentity have the binary data of a image in InputStream, for processing further its been converted as String in a library file[`String str = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity())`] , now am trying to get the input stream back from that String.

Take the below scenario for understanding the issue:

Working - ImageView is displayed with content

```
InputStream inStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(thisPhotoUri);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream);
ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.picture_frame);
view.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Issue - ImageView is not displayed with image

```
InputStream inStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(thisPhotoUri);
String str = inStream.toString();
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.picture_frame);
view.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Answer (score 1):

`InputStream.toString()` does not do, what you're expecting. It will call the `Object.toString()` method and you will get something like `java.io.InputStream@604c9c17`, not the real content of the stream!

Try a `System.out.println(str);` to see, what it's value is.

That's why you can't regenerate the original `InputStream` from this content, because it is not the **content** of the `InputStream`!

You have to read the stream in another way to get the content to the `String`! See: [Read/convert an InputStream to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly convert the InputStream to String. This might be the issue.

```
String str = inStream.toString();
```

[Take a look at this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-inputstream-to-string-in-java/) to identify the way of converting the InputStream to String.

Comment: Tried the string convertion as mentioned in the link, when i convert the string back to stream & pass it to bitmap factory it still return null.

Comment: Why you want to convert input stream to string, are you doing any modification to it?

Comment: Http calls are done inside a jar file and the response is given back as a json, so in this case the stream(image binary) is converted as string and added to json, the application layer is now trying to use the string to get the stream back & get the image.

Answer (score -1):

This should be what you are looking for:

`InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(yourString.getBytes("UTF-8"));`

Comment: Tried this, it doesnt help. As Bitmapfactory returns null, when passing the stream.